# What is "the school of tamarind and salt"

Tags: expressions

> You have **to study at the school of tamarind and salt** to learn more about their native custom.

What does **to study at the school of tamarind and salt** mean?

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what's meant without more context.

Comment: Would you please tell us something about where you found this sentence? That additional information will help someone write you a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamarind)

> *The consumption of **tamarind** is widespread due to its central role in the cuisines of the Indian subcontinent, South East Asia and America, particularly in Mexico.*

Like ***salt, tamarind*** is a spice/seasoning. OP's cited usage is totally non-standard (I can't find the original, and it's quite possible it's only ever been used *once* anyway).

To some extent the exact *meaning* will be context-specific, but essentially *study at the school of tamarind and salt* is a whimsical way of saying *consult with (Indian) chefs to find out more*.

I *think* probably all such "coinages" allude to *the school of hard knocks* - saying you went there is a whimsical way of saying you left formal education early - and learned to be *successful in real life* (through *experience*, which can sometimes be a tough way to learn), rather than "academically".